How to find Maximum Value of Venn Diagram?
A group of $40$ students appeared in an examination of $3$ subjects - Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry. It was found that all students passed in at least one of the subjects, $20$ students passed in Mathematics, 25 students passed in Physics, 16 students passed in Chemistry, at most $11$ students passed in both Mathematics and Physics, at most $15$ students passed in both Physics and Chemistry, at most $15$ students passed in both Mathematics and Chemistry. The maximum number of students passed in all the three subjects is?
Please explain the solution. Answer is 10

Try to find an expression to represent the problem using the Inclusion–exclusion principle:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle
Once you find it you can take the derivative of the expression and compare it to zero to find the max value.
For future times asking a question here, it will be better if you can try and write your attempt for solving the problem, what was the difficulty and further directions.
Welcome to the community.

Take a look at our guidelines for how to ask a good question, with emphasis on providing context. Your post is a bare problem statement with no context at all, which on this site can attract down votes and close votes.

A general approach is to use integer linear programming, with a nonnegative decision variable $x_S$ for each of the seven nonempty subsets $S$ of the three subjects and linear constraints to enforce the cardinalities.  For your example, the problem is to maximize $x_{111}$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_{001} + x_{011} + x_{101} + x_{111} &= 20 \tag1\label1\\
x_{010} + x_{011} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 25 \tag2\label2\\
x_{100} + x_{101} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 16 \tag3\label3\\
x_{001} + x_{010} + x_{011} + x_{100} + x_{101} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 40  \tag4\label4\\
x_{011} + x_{111} &\le 11 \tag5\label5\\
x_{110} + x_{111} &\le 15 \tag6\label6\\
x_{101} + x_{111} &\le 15 \tag7\label7
\end{align}
As you claimed, the maximum objective value is $10$, attained by $x_{001}=10$, $x_{010}=14$, $x_{100}=5$, $x_{110}=1$, $x_{111}=10$, and all other $x_S = 0$.

It turns out that the linear programming relaxation has maximum value $10.5$, and the corresponding dual variables provide a short certificate of optimality as follows.  Multiply the first three equality constraints \eqref{1} through \eqref{3} by $1/2$, the last equality constraint \eqref{4} by $-1/2$, the lower bounds $x_{011},x_{101}, x_{110}\ge 0$ by $-1/2$, and add everything up, yielding
$$x_{111} \le \frac{1}{2}\left(20 + 25 + 16 - 40\right) = 10.5.$$
